# getElementById .value no devuelve valor de input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

Tengo una función que comprueba si el valor de input esta vacío, si es así, se asigna un 5 a una variable, si no, el valor del input. Ahora pasa que el getElementById("num").value devuelve `<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">` , y debería ser su valor, no el tag.

Mi función:

```js
function b(){
    //Comprobación
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        let num = 5;
    }
    else{
        let num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    console.log(num); 
}

b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

En cambio, si escribo simplemente:

```js
function a(){
  let num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  console.log(num);
}
a()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Sí que funciona, y le introduce el valor.
¿Alguien sabe a que se debe? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es una pregunta bastante interesante, y me alegra haber coincidido con ella. Al principio parece impresionante pero investigando un poco en cómo funcionan los `ids` deja de ser una sorpresa.

Cuando creamos un elemento en el `html` con un `id` específico, el elemento estará disponible en nuestro objeto `window` para toda nuestra web, es decir, que cada vez que declaramos un `id`, se creará una variable con ese nombre que almacenará una referencia a ese elemento en el `html`:

```js
console.log(div)
console.log(myInput)

// O de manera equivalente
console.log(window.div)
console.log(window.myInput)
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Esto, en combinación con el alcance local de `let`, hacen ese efecto en tu código que puede confundir a más de uno (me incluyo cuando lo vi por primera vez).

Recordemos que una variable `let` solo existe entre las llaves en las que ha sido declarada. Es decir:

```js
function b(){
    //Comprobación
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        let num = 5;  //num solo existe acá, no existe fuera de este bloque
    }
    else{
        //num solo existe acá, no existe fuera de este bloque
        let num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    
    // Este num, se refiere a la variable global que se creó 
    // en window cuando declaraste el elemento con un id
    console.log(num); 
}

document.querySelector("#num").addEventListener('change',b)
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Se alinearon los planetas de la confusión porque le pusiste a la variable el mismo nombre que el `id`, pero si hubieras utilizado otro nombre hubieras obtenido el tan esperado error en estos casos:

```js
function b(){
    //Comprobación
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        let n = 5;
    }
    else{
        let n = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    console.log(n); 
}

b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Si declaras una variable con `let` dentro de un bloque `if` o un bloque `else` solo existirá en ese ámbito. Declara la variable fuera del bloque para evitar el problema:

```js
function b(){
    let num;
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        num = 5;
    }
    else{
        num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    console.log(num); 
}

b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Aunque quizás ahora que ya sabes la variable que se crea cuando declaras un id en tu código, quieras refactorizar tu código a esto (no recomendado), y seguiría funcionando:

```js
function b(){
    let n;
    if(num.value === ""){
        n = 5;
    }
    else{
        n = num.value;
    }
    console.log(n); 
}

b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Resumen:

- Para cada elemento en tu `html` declarado con un `id` se creará una propiedad en el objeto `windows` cuya `key` es el `id` y cuyo valor es una referencia al elemento.
- Las variables declaradas con `let` tienen alcance local (dentro de las llaves entre las que se declara) y no existen fuera de esas llaves.

Answer (score 0):

A que se debe no sabre decirte, pero lo podrías simplificar de la siguiente manera si quieres:

```js
function b() {
    let num = document.getElementById("num").value

    //Comprobación
    if(num == ""){
        num = 5;
    } 
   
    console.log(num); 
}

b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num" onchange="b()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Es que debes asignar un evento, sino, se leerá el valor del input al momento de interpretarse la función.

Debe hacer algo como esto:

```js
function b(){
    //Comprobación
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        let num = 5;
    }
    else{
        let num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    console.log(num); 
}

document.querySelector("#num").addEventListener('change',b)
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Es bueno recordarte que el valor de un input vacío es valga la redundancia vacío, por lo que en lugar de condicionar asi:

```
if(document.getElementById("num").value === "")
```

Debes hacerlo así:

```
if(document.getElementById("num"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale, creo saber el porqué de que no te muestra el 5.

Código JS Y HTML actualizado:

```js
function b(){
    //Comprobación
    if(document.getElementById("num").value === ""){
        var num = 5;
    }
    else{
        var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    }
    console.log(num); 
}
b()
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="num" name="num">
```

Cómo te pudiste dar cuenta, lo único que modifiqué fue el `let`, y por qué te muestra el tag? Bueno, hay cierta diferencia entre usar `let` a usar `var`, la diferencia es que con `let` si que puedes modificarla, pero no re declararla, eso no pasa con `var` con ella puedes modificar y re declarar la variable. `var` es más versátil y con ella solucionas el problema. Espero haberte ayudado:D